# My structure can not scan the double value in C

Tags: c, floating-point, double, precision, floating-accuracy

I can't figure it out what is happening.
It can reads two integer numbers, but it can not read double.
Its just become 0 and never change after scanning.

The output:

```
---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---

1. Display Employee Information
2. Add Employee
0. Exit
Please select from the above options: 2

Adding Employee
===============
Enter Employee ID: 1441
Enter Employee Age: 26
Enter Employee Salary: 7989.98

1. Display Employee Information
2. Add Employee
0. Exit

Please select from the above options: 1

EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY
======  ======= ==========
  1441       26       0.00
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 2 // Define Number of Employees "SIZE" to be 2

struct Employee
{
    int id;
    int age;
    double salary;
}; // Declare Struct Employee

/* main program */
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    double tempsalary = 0.0;

    int option = 0;
    printf("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n\n");

    struct Employee emp[SIZE] = { 0, 0, 0 };

    do
    {
        // Print the option list
        printf("1. Display Employee Information\n");
        printf("2. Add Employee\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");
        scanf("%d", &option); // Capture input to option variabl
        printf("\n");

        switch (option)
        {
            case 0: // Exit the program

                printf("Exiting Employee Data Program.\nGood Bye!!!");

                break;

            case 1:

                printf("EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
                printf("======  ======= ==========\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                {
                    printf("%6d%9d%11.2lf", emp[i].id, emp[i].age, emp[i].salary);
                    printf("\n");
                }

                break;

            case 2: // Adding Employee

                if (i > SIZE)
                {
                    printf("ERROR!!! Maximum Number of Employees Reached\n");
                }

                printf("Adding Employee\n");
                printf("===============\n");
                printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                scanf("%d", &emp[i].id);
                printf("Enter Employee Age: ");
                scanf("%d", &emp[i].age);
                printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
                scanf("%lf", &emp[i].salary);
                // printf("%.2lf",emp[i].salary);
                printf("\n");

                i++;

                break;

            default:
                printf("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");
        }

    } while (option != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: `if(i>SIZE) { printf("ERROR!! ...` ==> `if(i>=SIZE) ...`

Comment: In `case 1:` you are creating confusion by shadowing `i`. I suggest `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { ... }`. Note too, the loop ends at `i` not at `SIZE`.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/JIxi3t. Are you sure that you don't have a strange locale ? try with `7989,98`

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Warning: *always* check the return value from `scanf` function family. What is that? RTM.

Comment: With option 1, the output should be `EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY
======  ======= ==========
  1441       26    7989.98
     0        0       0.00`,  2  lines of employee info.  I suspect the code/input posted and OP's true code/input differ.

Comment: `struct Employee emp[SIZE] = { 0, 0, 0 };` --> `struct Employee emp[SIZE] = {{ 0, 0, 0}, { 0, 0, 0} };`

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you cannot use i in your case 1 to print information about employees. And when you print, you need to check that you do not exceed the maximum size of you array (SIZE) and the number of entries you entered.

Try this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 2 // Define Number of Employees "SIZE" to be 2

struct Employee
{
   int id;
   int age;
   double salary;
}; // Declare Struct Employee

/* main program */
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    double tempsalary = 0.0;

    int option = 0;
    printf("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n\n");

    struct Employee emp[SIZE] = { 0, 0, 0 };

    do
    {
        // Print the option list
        printf("1. Display Employee Information\n");
        printf("2. Add Employee\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");
        scanf("%d", &option); // Capture input to option variabl
        printf("\n");

        switch (option)
        {
            case 0: // Exit the program

                printf("Exiting Employee Data Program.\nGood Bye!!!");

                break;

            case 1:
                j = 0;
                printf("EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
                printf("======  ======= ==========\n");
                for (j = 0; (j < i) && (j < SIZE) ; j++)
                {
                    printf("%6d%9d%11.2lf", emp[j].id, emp[j].age, emp[j].salary);
                    printf("\n");
                }

                break;

            case 2: // Adding Employee

                if (i >= SIZE)
                {
                    printf("ERROR!!! Maximum Number of Employees Reached\n");
                }

                printf("Adding Employee\n");
                printf("===============\n");
                printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                scanf("%d", &emp[i].id);
                printf("Enter Employee Age: ");
                scanf("%d", &emp[i].age);
                printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
                scanf("%lf", &emp[i].salary);
                // printf("%.2lf",emp[i].salary);
                printf("\n");

                i++;

                break;

            default:
                printf("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");
        }

    } while (option != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `i` in the `for (int i = 0; i < SIZE: i++)` is 'legitimate'.  It is a new variable, hiding the previously defined variable `i` in the function.  It is ill-advised, but it is not wrong.  It doesn't even change the value of the variable in the main part of the function.  Its scope is strictly the `for` loop.